# Checkedlistbox SQL query to fill datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, checkedlistbox

im doing a c# project, in summery what i want is , the user will select number "1" or "0" from the checkedlistbox, and then the user will press the ok button and the sql query will work and the result will be displayed into a datagridview, its working fine with me but only once, i mean the user will select as example "1" then press ok and the result will be displayed with no problems, then he'll press the clear button and then if he choose "1" or "0" the result will be the same as he have choosed  firstly , so the result of "1" will be displayed,if someone would help me i'll begrateful, and that's my code for that :

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex);
this.vlm_Application_Data_SessionsTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSet1.vlm_Application_Data_Sessions,checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex);

this.datagridview11.Refresh();
```

the datagridview is binded dynamically from local database using this code:

```
this.datagridview11.DataSource = this.vlm_Application_Data_SessionsBindingSource;
this.vlm_Application_Data_SessionsBindingSource.DataSource = this.dataSet1.vlm_Application_Data_Sessions;
```

note that the exact query and code is working in the same form but in another datagridview using date time pickers instead of the checkedlistbox..

Comment: second time did you bind the datagrid again

Comment: yes, its the same code for run button

Comment: Can you add databind code also

Answer (score 0):

As per your above Query , the Data showed in datagridview is not getting updated.
Possible reasons data from the server is not getting binded with the datagridview control.

You may possibly try to use this.datagridview11.databind() method explicitly
to update the control.

Regards

Comment: theres no databind() after the "datagridview11." why ? o_O

theres only databindings which is not the solution..

Answer (score 0):

problem is solved after i added this codes to the clear button :

```
this.checkedListBox1.ResetText();
this.checkedListBox1.Refresh();
```